# Renaming variables not reliable when editing a Jupyter notebook in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

As can be seen in the screenshot I am renaming the variable `bdir` to `originalsDir` - and notice there are two additional usages after its definition:

[image]

But after confirming to `Refactor` only the variable itself is changed - and *not* its usages .. which now become *red* since they are orphaned:

[image]

Why would this be happening? I must believe this were some kind of corner case since a fundamental feature of variable renaming would not easily slip through Jetbrains QA ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename refactor for variables in the global scope requires indexing which requires a physical file and that's a problem with notebooks as the source code representation in PyCharm is a virtual file on top of real JSON content (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56473212/2787185).

This feature will certainly be implemented as the new Jupyter support development is a priority and in active state. The relevant ticket in the bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34670

Comment: Nice to hear. I did kind of realize the virtual file thing.  Maybe _pycharm_ can place an actual _file_ into the `cache` that is .. just a file.. and is used solely for historical purposes?  The amount of effort and space should both be small.

Comment: To be more clear: the way I'm handling these issues with the virtual file vs physical file is .. I periodically copy and paste the `.ipynb` code (not preview) contents into a different `.py` file in the IDE . _pycharm_ could do the same thing under the covers - that is keep a separate copy of the `.ipynb` in its cache and then obtain all of the benefits of a normal `python` file applied to that physical (hidden/background) file including refactoring and local history.

Comment: overall i'm impressed with the progress on the `jupyter` notebook integration: the debugger actually works and it's really nice to edit the contents mostly like a normal python file.