# Jupyter notebooks in pycharm do not have Local History support in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

`Local History` is an absolutely fundamental/crucial feature of `Jetbrains` IDE families - including `Pycharm`.  Why would it be missing for the `.ipynb` files?  Here is the right click/context menu - in which the `Show History` is missing:

[image]

In addition: the `Code Editing History Navigation` feature is not working in the notebooks: notice that the `Last Edit Location` option is disabled even though I had edited this notebook:

[image]

Why are basic/core code editing features missing for these notebooks?  Is there a way to enable them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notebook source code representation in PyCharm is basically a virtual file as a `.ipynb` itself is a JSON. This makes thing complicated as we don't want to show history for JSON but for Python representation. Local History is going to be eventually implemented as it's a core functionality indeed, but it will require some time as it has to be tweaked to support this case. The dedicated ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33557

Comment: I'll take a look at that ticket.. the support is not in place still nearly a year later.

Comment: Local history does exist for .ipynb files as of version 2020.3, but the problem seems to be that reverting a file does not update the source notebook. Even closing and reopening the reverted notebook seems to show the old contents. I must be missing something.

Comment: It seems that the only way to revert such notebook is to close the notebook, revert using the local history, go to folder, make a copy of the file, and then open this copy. If you open the original notebook the reversion does not appear.